# Spring data rest : Page and Specification Rest API is not returning any data

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, pagination, specifications

When i use Spring Boot + Data Rest + H2 API is not returning any data.?

```
  @GetMapping("pagination")
            List<Demo> findAll(Pageable pageable, @ModelAttribute Demo demo) {
                Specification<Demo> specification = DemoSpecification.search(demo);
                Page<Demo> page = demoService.findAll(specification, pageable);
                return page.getContent();
            }


    public class DemoSpecification {
        public static Specification<Demo> search(Demo demo) {

            return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

                if (demo != null && demo.getId() != null) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("id"), "%" + demo.getId() + "%"));
                }

                if (demo != null && demo.getName() != null) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), "%" + demo.getName() + "%"));
                }

                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
            };
        }
    }
```

/demo/pagination?page=5&name=Anil is not returning any Data.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/demo/page?name=Anil&page=5

returns empty content why..?

Comment: But generated query gave data.

/* select
        generatedAlias0 
    from
        Demo as generatedAlias0 
    where
        generatedAlias0.name like '%Anil%' */ select
            demo0_.id as id1_0_,
            demo0_.name as name2_0_ 
        from
            demo demo0_ 
        where
            demo0_.name like '%Anil%' limit 5 offset 0

Comment: 1 Anil
2 Anil
3 Anil
4 Anil
5 Anil